# Grails process dynamic javascript (output from gsp) as a resource

Tags: grails, plugins, resources

I have a JS file that is included in my GSP template as follows:

```
<r:script type="text/javascript">
    <g:render template="/javascript/common"/>
</r:script>
```

The `/javascript/common` outputs some dynamic JS e.g. pre-populates lists client side. It's dynamic per server restart i.e. it doesn't need to be generated per request, but rather more commonly on redeployment.

I'm wondering how I can process it as a resource using the resource plugin and get the ability to minify it and compress it etc.

There may be times where it would need to be refreshed. Is it possible to support refreshing it in a similar fashion to other resources i.e. when the underlying file is modified the plugin reloads it.

thanks ...

Comment: You might have a look at the Gsp Resources plugin http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-resources .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure it cooperates with the resource plugin would be to create [a custom ResourceMapper](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/6.%20Creating%20custom%20mappers.html)

Oversimplified version:

1. Create a file with ResourceMapper.groovy as the file suffix, in the `grails-app/resourceMappers` folder.
2. Decorate the class using `def phase = MapperPhase.GENERATION`
3. Implement `def map(resource, config) {}` to generate your resource when requested.

Your custom mapper will run once per deployment, then use the static generated file. All of the minify/compress, you're using will, of course, run *after* the GENERATION phase.

UPDATE: It does look like the Gsp Resources plugin @Ruben suggested would do what you're looking for.  You can see the [source](https://github.com/mckenfra/gsp-resources/blob/master/grails-app/resourceMappers/org/grails/plugin/gspresources/GspResourceMapper.groovy) for its custom mapper.